# Unable to validate PHP empty() in AJAX form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

I want to validate the form input with the PHP. `Empty()` in my php file doesn't return any result (no error message, form submits). The form works - it does submit the field - but I can submit a blank field. The AJAX returns *success* regardless. `<?php echo $error;?>` throws an `unidentified variable` error due to nothing being returned from the `empty()` function. I should mention that these are 3 different files.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$error= ''; 
$title = '';

if(isset($_GET)) {

    if (empty($_GET['page_title'])) {
        $error= 'Name is required';
    } else {
        $title = $_GET['page_title'];
    }
}
?>
```

**AJAX (Jquery)**

```
$(function() {
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'save_to_WP.php',
        data: {
            page_title: $('input[name="page_title"]').val()
        },
        success: function(e){
            alert('yay');
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type = "text" name="page_title" />
    <span class="error"><?php echo $error;?></span>
    <button type = "submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

I posted this chunk of code previously, but I believe the problem I was stating was actually a symptom of THIS issue. No wonder I didn't get an answer that worked, I was asking the wrong question.

I'd be grateful for any assistance or suggestions.

Comment: The PHP code doesn't emit any output, throw any errors, or do *anything* really.  It conditionally sets a variable, but never uses that variable.  There's no indication to the client that anything happened at all.  It's not clear to me what you're expecting the result of that AJAX call to be or why.  I would expect this PHP code to always successfully return a blank response.

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump($_GET)`?

Comment: If you want to use the ajax error, you need to return an http error code, for example a 500 error.

Comment: @David The form actually creates a WP post from an external source (the page with the form). There are two parts: the input field and the content which comes from Jquery getting elements from the page. That all works beautifully - I just want a little validation (don't we all...?). For debugging I stripped everything out except submitting the input field, just to see if trying to submit a blank field would throw an error like it should.

Comment: @crinkledMap: Perhaps you stripped out too much.  When you say "throw an error like it should", why do you think it *should*?  In the PHP code you're showing there is nothing being returned to the client.  No message, no error, nothing.  Just a blank successful response by default.  If some of the code you stripped out was doing that, we can't see it here.

Comment: @david I would expect to get:
1) Nothing - the form doesn't submit because the field is blank, or
2) "Name is required" (from the PHP), or
3) "Error" from the Ajax. 

None of the code I commented out locally and omitted here had any return functions. Other than the bit that sends that title input over to WP, this is it. I'd be happy to post it, but I've both left it in and commented it out, and it doesn't have an effect.

Comment: @crinkledMap: Well, 1) There's nothing in the JavaScript which stops the form from submitting, 2) The PHP code may indeed be setting the `$error` variable, but it doesn't return it to the client so the client never sees that text, 3) The AJAX `error` callback is only invoked if the server sends back an error code in the response (see another user's answer below), the code shown doesn't do that.  You're expecting things to automatically happen here, but I'm afraid that's not the case.  For any one of those three options you would need to write code to explicitly perform that action.

Answer (score 1):

You should return an error response from the server in order to trigger the ajax jQuery error callback:

```
<?php
    $error= ''; 
    $title = '';

    if(isset($_GET)) {
        if (empty($_GET['page_title'])) {
            $error= 'Name is required';
            header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
            echo $error;
        } else {
            $title = $_GET['page_title'];
            echo 'ok!';
        }
    }

?>
```